# Boost Asio UDP listening on all (or several) ports

Tags: c++, networking, boost, udp, boost-asio

Is it possible to have a boost asio udp client that is listening for messages on several ports at the same time? Or just listening for messages from any port?

For background (and because I am new to networking and probably not picking the best way to do this), essentially my problem is I have a main node kicking off processes on several other nodes in a cluster. When each child node finishes its process, it is to send it's results to another node that is waiting for results.  I was thinking it would be easiest to simply do a UDP broadcast from each child node, with each child node broadcasting on a unique port, and the listener listening on all ports.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP sockets need to bind to a specific port if they have to receive incoming messages destined for that port. If you want to listen on a multiple of ports, then you will have to open multiple UDP sockets and bind them to all those ports. The bind method accepts the port number on which you wish to receive messages: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/bind/overload1.html